# Problem with spacing sizes in theme.json

Tags: css, theme.json

I often use the following code in theme.json to define predefined spacing:

```
"spacingScale": {
    "steps": 5
},
"spacingSizes": [
    {
    "size": "min(20px, 2.5vw)",
    "slug": "20",
    "name": "S"
    },
    {
    "size": "min(40px, 2.5vw)",
    "slug": "40",
    "name": "M"
    },
    {
    "size": "min(60px, 5vw)",
    "slug": "60",
    "name": "L"
    },
    {
    "size": "min(80px, 5vw)",
    "slug": "80",
    "name": "XL"
    },
    {
    "size": "min(100px, 5vw)",
    "slug": "100",
    "name": "XXL"
    }
]
```

However, there is a problem for me here. I would like the top and bottom spacing to always remain in pixel dimensions but keep the VW for left and right. Is there a solution for this with which I can go into the theme.json or would a different CSS calculation maybe help?

Hope it is understandable what I mean. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Can nobody help here? Or is the question not understandable? I've already tried clamp and min/max, but can't find a solution.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/264898)